# I want to have a CSS3 loading spin animation which is similar to HTML5's video loader

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have some codes now but it does not feel 'natural' like HTML5's video element's loader.

How can I finetune this CSS3 loader to be more similar to the video element's one?

Right now I have 2 elements rotating constantly with a short delay in between.

I just don't see if I need to raise this delay, or need some more sophisticated animation with bezier:

```css
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.loader {
  color: #555555;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.4em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.loader:before {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.4em;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10.4em 0 0 10.4em;
  top: -0.2em;
  left: -0.2em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 5.2em 5.2em;
  transform-origin: 5.2em 5.2em;
  -webkit-animation: load 1.2s infinite ease 0.2s;
  animation: load 1.2s infinite ease 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.1);
}
.loader:after {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.4em;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0 10.4em 10.4em 0;
  top: -0.2em;
  left: 5.0em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0.0em 5.2em;
  transform-origin: 0.0em 5.2em;
  -webkit-animation: load 1.2s infinite ease;
  animation: load 1.2s infinite ease;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader .label {
font-size: 16px;
position: absolute;
top: 110%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
z-index: 1;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body bgcolor=black>

<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>

<div class="loader"><div class="label">Loading...</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

For example here is a simple spinner which I'm looking for (it also changes its color, but it is out of this question):
[image]

Material design also uses this as loader and here is a JS + CSS solution but I need something **without SVG** (pure CSS3): https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Style-Loading-Spinner-with-jQuery-CSS3/

Comment: define "similar to the video element?" I've always used bootstrap spinners. [https://getbootstrap.com/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/spinners/])

Comment: This is error 404. Similar to what video element does upon loading a stream on Chrome browser.

Comment: Bootstrap spinner seems a fixed curve rotating. In html5's example the spinner is not a fixed curve, it has dynamics. Will find some good demonstration soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is seeking for this, I have found a very nice solution:

https://materializecss.com/preloader.html.

It's a pure CSS solution, no SVG and no JS is needed.